# Samsung Galaxy Tab S cannot get listFiles from "Download" directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am now the proud owner of a Samsung Galaxy Tab S as I am starting to port a smart phone app to the tablet format.

I have created a "Download" directory on my SD card and there was already a "Download" directory on the device because I had downloaded something from an email.

I use the following code to get a list of files to loop over to read and add to my TextView but on the tablet the java code never retrieves the list of files:

The same code works fine on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

```
private InputStream getDownloadIntercessionStream(String fileName)
{   
    File[] paths;
    File downloadDir = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    downloadDir = (File) Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    paths = downloadDir.listFiles();
    if (paths != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            File tmpFile = paths[i];
            if (fileName.equals(tmpFile.getName())) {
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

Kind regards, Gordon

Comment: Hi People any one out there seen this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the manifest file for kitkat work nicely for me:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just for someone, who will have same issue.

I had this problem, solution was adding a permission to manifest:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Be careful to not garble "uses-permission" and "permission".